# configuration in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-framework-mvc

i am new to ZF and i am making a project in ZF .i got basic knowledge of ZF but need more.
i studied configuration in ZF in many different ways like

1. Using Array Configuration
2. Creating File Configuration
3. Using INI File Configuration
4. Using XML File Configuration

i need to know what is best and efficient way among all these  in sense of Maintainability and security ??
also can anyon plz tell me (Quick advise)  how to start my first project so that its easy for me in order to maintain and upgrade.i am bit confuse with layouts that is  header , footer and sidebar etc
how to intigrate this in my bootstrap like this but its not working

```
// Register the autoloader
  require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
 Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
// Initialise Zend_Layout's MVC helpers
Zend_Layout::startMvc(array('layoutPath' => ROOT_DIR.'/app/views/layouts'));
```

Comment: run through this tutorial http://akrabat.com/ and maybe the quickstart from the Zend Framework Documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html. Then ask the question again, I think you'll have different view of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For configuration the answer is: use what you like best. All Zend_Config classes have same functionality. They just differ with the syntax.

As for something not working you  must write more details. Again - what do you mean by 'not working'? What are the errors?

Comment: i have header,footer right now i want to renders it in every page that is layout how can i procede

Comment: Write some more code - how does your layout look like? What isn't working?